# Are multiple foreign key constraints on the same column "ORed" or "ANDed"

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

In other words, if I have two foreign key constraints on the same column, will both constraints have to be met or just one in order to successfully add the record?

Comment: . . All the constraints need to be met, foreign or otherwise.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Succinct and to the point, sucks that I have to add a nearly identical relation to address that one problem though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several constraints defined on a table, then when an operation happens on the table ALL constraints needs to be met. Please note that this applies to ALL types of constraints, not only foreign constraints (that you initially questionned about) :

- UNIQUE
- NOT NULL
- CHECK
- FOREIGN KEY

See [the sqlite documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#constraints) for more information about table ad column constraints.